# Conditional probability on card drawing

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I take an ordinary shuffled deck of cards and keep flipping them over until the first ace appears, which is card #14. What's the probability the next card is the eight of hearts.

> At first glance, one might think the answer to this is 1/51. There are
> 52 cards, one of which has a known position. Therefore, there are only
> 51 possibilities for the 15th card. However, this is not taking the
> other known information into consideration. We might not know exactly
> where the remaining aces are, but we can be certain they are lying
> somewhere after card #14. Thus, we have some condition to our
> probability.
>
> To tackle this, let's work on two probabilities: first, what is the
> probability the eight of hearts is in the second split, and second,
> what is the probability the eight of hearts is the next card given
> that it is in the second split. (multiplying a conditional probability
> with the condition gives you the intersection of those probabilities.)
>
> We can utilize compliments and rephrase the probability of the eight
> of hearts being in the second split as the probability it is not in
> the first split. There are 13 cards (excluding the known ace) in the
> first split. The total possible number of cards that can be in that
> split is 50, as all the aces come at index 14 and after. Thus, the
> probability the eight of hearts is in the second split is 1 - 13/50 =
> 37/50
>
> Given that the eight of hearts is in the second split, what is the
> probability it is next? There are 38 cards in the remaining split
> (again not including the known ace) all of which are equally likely to
> be selected next resulting in a 1/38 conditional probability.
>
> Multiplying these probabilities gives us 37/1900, the probability that
> the 15th card is the eight of hearts. Is this correct?

Comment: There are $48$ cards that can appear before the first ace, not $50$ as you suggest. Otherwise, your approach appears to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${52-5 \choose 13}$ ways to choose first $13$ cards without $4$ Aces and eight of hearts.

There are ${4 \choose 1}$ ways to choose an Ace for $14$th card.

There is only one way to place eight of hearts at $15$th location.

There are $(52-15)!$ ways of placing rest of the cards starting from $16$ th position.

So overall there are ${52-5 \choose 13} \times {4 \choose 1} \times 1 \times (52-15)!$ arrangements with first ace at position $14$ followed by eight of hearts in position $15$.

And overall there are ${52-4 \choose 13} \times {4 \choose 1} \times (52-14)!$ arrangements with first ace at position $14$ in position $15$.

So conditional probability that first ACE is in position $14$ followed by eight of heats given that first ACE is in position $14$:

$$\frac{{52-5 \choose 13} \times {4 \choose 1} \times 1 \times (52-15)!}{{52-4 \choose 13} \times {4 \choose 1} \times (52-14)!} = \frac{35}{48 \times 38}$$

Answer (score 1):

No.   The method works, but you miscalculated a value.

Let us try another route ...

*When the first ace is card #14*, then there are $\binom{52-14-1}{3}$ ways to place the aces with the $8\heartsuit$ following the first ace out of the $\binom {52-14}{3}\binom{52-4}{1}$ ways to place the aces and $8\heartsuit$ in total.

$$\dfrac{37\cdot36\cdot35}{38\cdot37\cdot39\cdot48} =\left(1- \dfrac{13}{48}\right)\cdot\dfrac 1 {38}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not right.

> The total possible number of cards that can be in that split is 50, as all the aces come at index 14 and after.

You are forgetting the datum: the card at position 14 is the first ace.

Let $U$ be the event that our special card (eight of hearts) appears in the upper section, ie, after the position 14. And let $U^c$ be its complementary event.

Let $S$ be success event: the special card appears in position 15.

Let $E$ be the given event: "the first ace occurred in position 14".

We want $P(S|E)$. To introduce $U$ :

$$\begin{align}
P(S \mid E) &= P(S, U \mid E) + P(S, U^c \mid E) \tag{1}\\
 &= P(U \mid E)\, P(S\mid U,E)  \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, $P(U\mid E) = 1 - P(U^c \mid E) = 1 - \frac{13}{48}=\frac{35}{48}$

And, yes, $P(S\mid U,E) = \frac{1}{38}$